# Keep installed RPMs in sync

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm

What is the best way to keep several CentoS/RH 5 servers keep the same set of RPM's? I.e., when I install or update an RPM on one of them using a common YUM repository, make the other servers update/install it too.

Keeping everything updated to the latest version of everything from the repository is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following ideas may also help you:

- Use the yum versionlock plugin (`yum install yum-plugin-versionlock`) to lock specific packages to a specific version or release.
- Use [Katello](http://www.katello.org/) or the older [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/) for a more centralized management tool, similar to Red Hat Satellite. It allows you to create custom software channels with specific packages in them.

Comment: +1 for spacewalk; it's clean, and scales quite well.

Comment: awesome! spacewalk is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 10):

Pick your method.

- Roll your own repo and keep this updated to the last version you want.
- Use a tool like Puppet.
- Use a distributed shell to issue the update commands.
- Use one machine as master and script a tool that reads the package list on the master and uses this on the others.

Comment: 1 already doing that, not an option
2 a bit overkill
3 & 4 - I was hoping there is already something to avoid doing this.

Thanks anyway

Comment: 1) is the best method, imho. Its the best for allowing you to stage the updates and test them before having all other machines use them.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the tools/ideas listed, another nice solution for this task is [Pulp](http://www.pulpproject.org/).